# Can not parse JSON in REST webservices

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, pojo

I have developed web service that can parse XML payload using JAXB framework. Now I need to extend this web service to parse the same payload in JSON format. The below logic that works for XML payload doesn't work for JSON payload. Appreciate your inputs.

**XML Payload**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LinkUserToGroup>
<groups>
    <group>
        <id>dbb8</id>
    </group>
    <group>
        <id>ce50</id>
    </group>
</groups>
</LinkUserToGroup>
```

**JSON Payload(which doesn't work)**

```
{
  "LinkUserToGroup": {
    "groups": {
      "group": [
        { "id": "dbb8" },
        { "id": "ce50" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

POJO Classes

**LinkUserToGroup.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "LinkUserToGroup")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class LinkUserToGroup {

    @JsonProperty("groups")
    @XmlElement(name = "groups")
    private List<Groups>  groupsList;

    public List<Groups> getGroupsList() {
        return groupsList;
    }

    public void setGroupsList(List<Groups> groupsList) {
        this.groupsList = groupsList;
    }
}
```

**Groups.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "groups")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Groups {

    @XmlElement(name = "group")
    @JsonProperty("group")
    private List<GroupVO>  groups;

    public List<GroupVO> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(List<GroupVO> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }

}
```

**GroupVO.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "group")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class GroupVO {

  @JsonProperty("id")   
  @XmlElement(name = "id")  
  private String id;

  public String getID() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setURI(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

**service.java**

```
    @POST
    @Path("/{id}/groups")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response addGroupToUser(@PathParam("id") String key, LinkUserToGroup grpList) {

    List<Groups> groups = grpList.getGroupsList();
    List<GroupVO> groupVO;
    for (Groups gr : groups) {
        groupVO = gr.getGroups();
            for(GroupVO g : groupVO){
                eachGroupID = g.getID();
                logger.debug(" Current Group is::"+eachGroupID);
            }
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
```

I am getting null pointer exception at ***for (Groups gr : groups)***

**Stack Trace**

```
May 20, 2017 10:43:42 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.services.UserGroupWSOperations.addGroupToUser(UserGroupWSOperations.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
```

Java Build Path for this project is below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no grouplist available in the JSON data that you send that's why `grpList.getGroupsList()` returns `null`.
From the POJO definition of `LinkUserToGroup`, the key `groups` should be a JSON array. Please try with the following JSON data.

```
{
   "groups": [
      {
         "group": [
            {
               "id": "dbb8"
            },
            {
               "id": "ce50"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. I tried with above JSON data but I am still getting null pointer exception. Any other suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Is `grpList.getGroupsList()` still returns null?

Comment: Yes. It is still returning null.

Comment: What if we send the JSON payload as `{
   "LinkUserToGroup": {
      "groups": [
         {
            "group": [
               {
                  "id": "dbb8"
               },
               {
                  "id": "ce50"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}`

Comment: same error even with above suggested payload. Not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Can you share your dependencies?

Comment: i updated main thread with list of jars i am using in this project.

Comment: We don't need the key `LinkUserToGroup` in the JSON object it is the root object. I've updated the answer